# How is voltage regulated on the output of this supply?

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

This lil' piece of eye candy is a portion of an SMPS schematic. How do the TL431 and optocoupler work together to regulate the output voltage? Moreover, and I'm assuming this plays a role in it too, how is the resistance of the potentiometer adjusted by their interactions?

Full schem: https://archive.org/details/the-art-of-electronics-3rd-ed-2015_202008/page/665/mode/2up
[image]

Comment: This is only half of a circuit. Where's the other side of the optocoupler?

Answer (score 1):

Voltage too high -> TL431 draws more current through opto

Voltage too low -> TL431 draws less current through opto.

The other half of the circuit uses that signal to regulate the output.  This is a very common use case for a TL431.  The Pot sets the actual voltage.